# How do I automatically update my TextView of Latitude and Longitude?

Tags: java, android

How do I automatically update my TextView of Latitude and Longitude, when my location change

I build a app that save my location every x time in Mysql BD, and only i need that my TextView update when Location change.

Below i atacch the preview image of my app

TextView of Latitude and Longitude

```
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    TextView longitude =  findViewById(R.id.t_longitude);
    TextView latitude =  findViewById(R.id.t_latitude);

    longitude.setText("Longitude: " + location.getLongitude());
    latitude.setText("Latitude: " + location.getLatitude());

 }
```

This is my preview

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a `LocationListener` to use it's method that is `onLocationChanged`

> LocationListener return new latitude and longitude whenever user's
>   location change.

So first implement `LocationListener` then override it's method `onLocationChanged` as,

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {

      // Here's "newLocation" is the change in location of user.   
      // Do here what you want to do on change in location of user.     

}
```

For more details check this https://github.com/adityasonel/AndroidLocationChecker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/adityasonel/androidlocationchecker/FusedLocationProviderApiTracker.java

Answer (score -1):

There are numerous ways to get it done

- Interface for callbacks
- Timer thread
- Broadcast
- Event bus

The best way to go with this is to use an interface or event bus for call back, Implement an interface in your activity and provide its reference to you location manager class. As soon as the location changes the call the interface method to notify the class.

Comment: Please comment for the downvoting. i would love to know your view on it